# Simpler Way To Build Dict of Frequencies

Tags: python

When doing practice problems, I often times need to build a dict with keys as elements from an array and values as frequencies in which they appear.  I usually do something like:

```
charFreqs = {}
for c in myStr:
      if c in charFreqs:
           charFreqs[c] += 1
      else:
           charFreqs[c] = 1
```

This works fine, but I am wondering if there is a more concise method.  It seems like a lot of code to accomplish a pretty simple and common task.

Comment: Yes, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Simply do `charFreqs = Counter(myStr)`

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/202229). Look at the solution using `Counter`, not the accepted solution with `list.count()`

Answer (score 1):

I like using a defaultdict for this sort of thing.

```
import collections
charFreqs = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in myStr:
    charFreqs[c] += 1
```